# K&R Exercise 1-8 Counting blanks, tabs, and new lines

Tags: c

I'm going through K&R's book, and one of the exercises is to count the blanks, tabs, and new lines from input. But whenever I run the following code, it only correctly counts the blanks, tabs, and new lines for everything above the last new line. If there's no new line, it doesn't count anything.

```
hey how
```

returns

```
0 0 0
```

and

```
hey how
hey how
hey how
```

returns

```
2 0 2
```

If I had tabbed instead of using spaces it would be 0 2 2.
The spaces and tabs seem dependent on the new line, and I don't know why. So how do I get this to work so it doesn't require a new line at the end?
Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* counts blanks, tabs, and new lines */

main()
{
    int c, blanks, tabs, nl;
    blanks = 0;
    tabs = 0;
    nl = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')
            ++blanks;
        if(c == '\t')
            ++tabs;
        if(c == '\n')
            ++nl;

    }
    printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d\n" , blanks , tabs , nl);
}
```

Comment: How are you feeding your input into the program? From a file, or typing it in? If you type it, what do you do to signal end-of-file?

Comment: How are you running this program? Are you piping or redirecting your input into it, or are you running it and typing your input?

Comment: `getchar()` is obviously through keyboard or through piping(i still think keyboard)

Comment: I'm typing it in. I use CTRL-C for EOF.

Comment: That's your problem. CTRL-C is not EOF. It's ["interrupt the program"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_(POSIX)#SIGINT). EOF is CTRL-D. I'm surprised you're getting any output at all with CTRL-C, because that kills the program for me...

Comment: Is it supposed to just put ^D?

Comment: On Unix, it is typically control-D; you can check by running `stty -a` and looking at the EOF character specified.  On Windows, it would be control-Z.  Also, control-D actually just flushes any pending input to the terminal (so it can no longer be edited with backspace — I mean, the erase character).  If you do that at the beginning of a line, there are zero characters available, so a pending read returns 0, and that is treated as EOF by the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different keyboard shortcut. You don't want to kill the program, you want to simulate end-of-file with the appropriate key combination:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: Kills the program.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Signals EOF in Windows.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: Signals EOF in Linux.

Comment: I'm using Windows, but CTRL-Z only puts ^Z. Same with CTRL-D. I guess it would help to know that I'm using CodeLite.

Comment: Never mind, I realized I have to have it on a new line. And that if I didn't want to count a new line, I have to put it twice. Thanks for your help.